# Aggregate an array of objects by keys

Tags: javascript, aggregate

I have the following arrays of contexts that I would like to output in a more user friendly and aggregated way. I basically want to show each combination grouped by each property. For example, for the below context array

```
const contexts = [
  { channel: 'email', preset: 'christmas', field: 'preamble bottom' },
  { channel: 'web', preset: 'christmas', field: 'preamble bottom' },
  { channel: 'email', preset: 'deal', field: 'preamble top' },
  { channel: 'email', preset: 'sale', field: 'preamble top' },
  { channel: 'web', preset: 'deal', field: 'preamble top' },
  { channel: 'web', preset: 'sale', field: 'preamble top' }
];
```

I would like the following in response

```
{
  'email, web':
    {
      'christmas': 'preamble bottom',
      'deal, sale': 'preamble top'
    }
}
```

I am able to do this by grouping on the channel and preset but I'm struggling to get a generic solution. For example the context array could also look like this

```
const contexts = [
  { channel: 'email', preset: 'deal', field: 'vignette' },
  { channel: 'email', preset: 'deal', field: 'headline' },
  { channel: 'web', preset: 'deal', field: 'vignette' },
  { channel: 'web', preset: 'deal', field: 'headline' }
];
```

And should produce the following response

```
{
  'email, web':
    {
      'deal': 'vignette, headline'
    }
}
```

Any ideas? It feels like there should be some elegant solution to this.

Comment: Can't yet come up with a clean and satisfying solution but I guess this would be a good use case for Set https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start grouping from the `field` and work your way to the `channel`. Hope this helps.

```js
const contexts = [
    { channel: 'email', preset: 'christmas', field: 'preamble bottom' },
    { channel: 'web', preset: 'christmas', field: 'preamble bottom' },
    { channel: 'email', preset: 'deal', field: 'preamble top' },
    { channel: 'email', preset: 'sale', field: 'preamble top' },
    { channel: 'web', preset: 'deal', field: 'preamble top' },
    { channel: 'web', preset: 'sale', field: 'preamble top' }
];

const contexts2 = [
    { channel: 'email', preset: 'deal', field: 'vignette' },
    { channel: 'email', preset: 'deal', field: 'headline' },
    { channel: 'web', preset: 'deal', field: 'vignette' },
    { channel: 'web', preset: 'deal', field: 'headline' }
];

const group = (arr) => {

    const byField = new Set(arr.map(({ field }) => field));

    const byPreset = Array.from(byField).reduce((acc, val) => {

        const keys = new Set(arr.map(({ field, preset }) => field === val ? preset : null)
                                .filter((item) => item));

        const key = Array.from(keys).join(',');

        acc[key] = acc[key] ? `${acc[key]},${val}` : val;

        return acc;

    }, {});

    return Object.keys(byPreset).reduce((acc, val) => {

        const fields = val.split(',');

        const keys = new Set(arr.filter(({ channel, preset }) => fields.some((item) => item === preset))
                                .map(({ channel }) => channel));

        const key = Array.from(keys).join(',');

        acc[key] = { ...acc[key], [val]: byPreset[val] };

        return acc;

    }, {});
};

console.log(group(contexts));

console.log(group(contexts2));
```